# Sluggish Sharepoint Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performance, iis

I have Sharepoint 2010 application that runs smoothly during certain times of day however, whenever it feels like:
the CPU usage hits 100%;
the ASP Request Execution Time indicator flashes a warning;
the Processor Queue Length indicator  flashes a warning and 
the Memory indicator flashes a warning.

Sometimes, not a single warning is flashed.

I have been using Idera Sharepoint Manager

I have increased the cache limit and that seemed to alleviate the problem for a little while.
We've also increased from 1 to 4 processors.

The warnings still appear during various times of day and these are not constant.
I have cancelled out the probability of timer jobs slowing down the application.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what are your servers specs?

Comment: I second TZHX - the info provided is pretty vague. A wild guess - any search crawl that may be involved?

Comment: It’s a VM with 4GB RAM

There is no search crawl schedule setup on it

Comment: Is it part of a farm, or a stand-alone install? What's the clock speed? 4GB RAM sounds dangerously low to me, most SP2010 VM's I've used sit above that level when idle.

Comment: This is our dev environment. It has a SQL server and an App server on the farm. We've attached a piece of the production content db on this dev server.Clock speed is 2.53 Ghz, 

The problem is not with our VM though, the issue is at our client on their production environment which are in a farm and have 8GB RAM each

Comment: We've upped to RAM o 8GB on the dev box. Same warning messages. I was told that there could be a bottleneck somewhere. I dont see anything. Is there anything i can try?